# is there a seo penalty for 2 versions of navigation in html? (depending on media query called)

Tags: navigation, responsive-design, media-queries

I am building a responsive website.  The desktop version has the navigation across the bottom inside the footer. When the media query kicks in, I want my navigation to be a dropdown at the top instead. That requires a different html setup so, css alone wont move it properly and therefore media queries alone can't help.

With that said, I will need 2 sets of the navigation links in the html.  one for desktop and one for mobile. One will of course gets "display:none;" based on the current media query.

Is there any penalty with google for this? I mean virtually all websites have multiple links on same pages that go to the same url so I don't consider that duplicate content but the source code would have lets say #navigation_desktop and #navigation_mobile in the source code.

I wish I could use the same navigation for both but css alone can move it around properly. its simple different coding and div structures.  Any input on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly doubt you would be penalised - Googlebot is quite clever.  If you are that worried the HTML5 specification has a [`<nav>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element) element that makes a clear semantic distinction from page content.

The w3 page advises you still markup lists as normal, eg:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link
    <li><a href="#">link ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you @Emissary so what you are saying is that in html 5 I can place my navigation in multiple places within the <nav> tag?  Just like on this site I suppose: http://bradfrostweb.com. Actually, I dont think using that html5 tag is even required.

Comment: The `<nav>` tag isn't required, but might help to indicate to search spiders that it's navigation content, and might mitigate any penalties for the repeated content.

Comment: @all thanks Adrian - yes not required it's purely semantic.  You can have as many "nav" blocks as you like (though I would add: don't nest them).